# Custom content control default content

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, contentcontrol

I have a WPF custom content control inherits from Control and when developer drags this control from toolbox i want it to have a default content like expander control has.

```
<Expander>
     <Grid />
 </Expander>
```

How can i do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of inheriting from Control, you'll need to inherit from [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx#inheritanceContinued).

Here's a [sample blog post](http://mostlydevelopers.com/blog/post/2009/03/30/Silverlight-Custom-Content-Control.aspx) showing how this can be done.  (The post is using Silverlight, but the technique is identical for WPF.)

Comment: link is dead...